# Is there a more efficient way of writing this query?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, database-design

To save on the number of queries I execute in Postgres, I want to try and return as much data as possible in a single query. Here's a simple case demonstrating my naive solution, where I want to return all assets and all attribute IDs related to assets. Assets have many Attributes, which are tied via

```
SELECT assets.id, ARRAY(
    SELECT attributes.id
    FROM attributes
    WHERE attributes.asset_id = assets.id
) as attributes
FROM assets
LIMIT 100;
```

Running this in Postgres returns a data set which looks like this:

```
id      attributes       
3017    "{8948,9386}"
```

Right now the ORM would need to run that inner query separately, which seems to me like a less efficient way of performing the same task by delegating it to a different part of the application. While nested queries are awful, at least this way I'm not making multiple potentially-expensive database calls.

But there's at least one big issue with this approach: returning a second column from the `assets` table roughly doubles the amount of time. Returning only the `id` column takes 4893ms, returning `id` and `name` takes 8819ms, returning three columns takes 10744ms...it only gets worse with each column added to the query. Not really a scalable solution. Plus I want to retrieve multiple relations per row, so there could potentially be multiple subqueries like this for each row, which is definitely going to get more expensive.

**EDIT:** Per request, I ran EXPLAIN ANALYSE against this query.

Including `assets.id`:

```
"Seq Scan on assets  (cost=0.00..1804514.69 rows=142204 width=4) (actual time=0.059..2306.204 rows=142178 loops=1)"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on attributes  (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=142178)"
"          Recheck Cond: (asset_id = assets.id)"
"          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on attributes_asset_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=142178)"
"                Index Cond: (asset_id = assets.id)"
"Total runtime: 2674.115 ms"
```

Including `assets.id` and `assets.name`:

```
"Seq Scan on assets  (cost=0.00..1804514.69 rows=142204 width=20) (actual time=0.058..2330.947 rows=142178 loops=1)"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on attributes  (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=142178)"
"          Recheck Cond: (asset_id = assets.id)"
"          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on attributes_asset_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=142178)"
"                Index Cond: (asset_id = assets.id)"
"Total runtime: 2693.455 ms"
```

**EDIT 2**: Per request, here's a (lightly obfuscated) version of the schemas of the tables in question:

```
-- Table: ta_main.assets

-- DROP TABLE ta_main.assets;

CREATE TABLE ta_main.assets
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  field1 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field2 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field3 smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
  field4 date,
  field5 json,
  field6 text,
  field7 text,
  field8 text,
  field9 date,
  field10 date,
  field11 date,
  field12 text,
  field13 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field14 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field15 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field16 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field17 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field18 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field19 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field20 date,
  field21 date,
  field22 date,
  field23 text,
  field24 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field25 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field26 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field27 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field28 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field29 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field30 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field31 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field32 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field33 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field34 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field35 date,
  field36 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field37 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field38 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field39 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field40 json,
  field41 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field42 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field43 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field44 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field46 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field47 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field48 text,
  field49 date,
  field50 text,
  field51 text,
  field52 date,
  field53 double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field54 integer,
  field55 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  field56 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated timestamp with time zone,
  _deleted boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT asset_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE ta_main.assets
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Index: ta_main.assets_deleted_idx

-- DROP INDEX ta_main.assets_deleted_idx;

CREATE INDEX assets_deleted_idx
  ON ta_main.assets
  USING btree
  (_deleted);


-- Trigger: update_timestamp_assets on ta_main.assets

-- DROP TRIGGER update_timestamp_assets ON ta_main.assets;

CREATE TRIGGER update_timestamp_assets
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON ta_main.assets
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE global.update_timestamp();
```

And for assets

```
  -- Table: ta_main.attributes

  -- DROP TABLE ta_main.attributes;

  CREATE TABLE ta_main.attributes
  (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    asset_id integer NOT NULL,
    related_id integer,
    type smallint NOT NULL,
    description text,
    flag smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    value double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    nbv double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    acc double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    eul integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    quantity double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    quantity_extra double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    added_by text,
    is_import boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    is_donated boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated timestamp with time zone,
    _deleted boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT adjustment_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT asset_fkey FOREIGN KEY (asset_id)
        REFERENCES ta_main.assets (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT related_fkey FOREIGN KEY (related_id)
        REFERENCES ta_main.attributes (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
  )
  WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
  );
  ALTER TABLE ta_main.attributes
    OWNER TO postgres;

  -- Index: ta_main.attributes_deleted_idx

  -- DROP INDEX ta_main.attributes_deleted_idx;

  CREATE INDEX attributes_deleted_idx
    ON ta_main.attributes
    USING btree
    (_deleted);

  -- Index: ta_main.fki_asset_fkey

  -- DROP INDEX ta_main.fki_asset_fkey;

  CREATE INDEX fki_asset_fkey
    ON ta_main.attributes
    USING btree
    (asset_id);

  -- Index: ta_main.fki_related_fkey

  -- DROP INDEX ta_main.fki_related_fkey;

  CREATE INDEX fki_related_fkey
    ON ta_main.attributes
    USING btree
    (related_id);


  -- Trigger: update_timestamp_attributes on ta_main.attributes

  -- DROP TRIGGER update_timestamp_attributes ON ta_main.attributes;

  CREATE TRIGGER update_timestamp_attributes
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON ta_main.attributes
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE global.update_timestamp();
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on these two tables?

Comment: The `id` column is indexed on both, as are any foreign key columns like `adjustments.asset_id`

Comment: Have you looked at the query plans for one/two/etc columns - post the results of EXPLAIN ANALYSE select.....

Comment: @simonatrcl see my edited post; the query plans for the two queries are basically identical with no accounting for the time difference.

Comment: Looks like the one with 2 columns is 20ms faster than the one with 1. That shouldn't be a problem, surely?

Comment: What are the times if you use a join instead of a subquery? If a join is faster, then aggregating the results should not take much more.

Comment: @simonatrcl That number is odd to me, it doesn't actually match with reality at all given how in reality that second query runs at twice the time.

Comment: @fog I'm not totally clear on how I'd do that and get the same style of data?

Comment: At first glance I would expect the ARRAY style query to use many more server resources, although if you have a really bad network the difference might not be noticiable. On the speed of the query, I'd expect EXPLAIN is showing the amount of time on the server; it may include network time as well; it won't include time taken to display the results.

Comment: You can do a group by on the "common" columns and then use a function like array_agg to aggregate some columns into arrays.

Comment: See @TavoloPerUno's answer for details, but I did try the array_agg version of the query and it doesn't really improve things. As for network latency, I did try and negate that by running the query on the database server, it shouldn't factor in to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this? This seems to eliminate the inner query.

```
SELECT assets.id, ARRAY_AGG(attributes.id) FROM assets LEFT OUTER JOIN attributes ON assets.id = attributes.asset_id GROUP BY assets.id
```

Comment: I checked the speed of this query and yours on an assets table with 2463 rows which is in a relationship with an attributes table with 3797 rows. This query executed in 75 ms while the query provided by you took 1863 ms.

Comment: I tried running it against my live database and it ran about 1000ms slower than the query I provided above, do you have any additional indexes set up? Also it may be worth adding more columns to your test table for comparison as that seems to have a notable impact on performance.

Comment: My asset table has about 28 columns, 3 of which are of XML type and my attribute column has 21 columns. Both id's are indexed. Besides this relationship, my assets table has about 9 other foreign key relationships and my attributes table has about 7 other foreign key relationships. Would it be possible to disclose your table schema? It is quite odd we have totally conflicting execution times.

Comment: More pointers : Are you running Postgres 8.4 or below? That [could](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18D75C5016995C42BDFE90D1EF1FB1BD064D5410@atl-intexch.tcore.com) be a cause. [This](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54719/slow-queries-related-to-subqueries-using-aggregation) looks more like your problem case too.

Comment: The schemas are in my edited question above; I'm running these against 8.4. And yeah that does look fairly similar to what I'm working with here, it looks a lot like a more complex version of your approach.

Comment: [Looks](http://packages.trisquel.info/changelogs/pool/main/p/postgresql-8.4/postgresql-8.4_8.4.22-0ubuntu0.12.04/changelog) more like an attribute of Postgres 8.4, which makes array_agg slower.

Comment: SELECT assets.id, trim( trailing ',' from xmlagg((attributes.id::character varying ||',')::xml)::character varying) FROM assets LEFT OUTER JOIN attributes ON assets.id = attributes.asset_id GROUP BY assets.id ORDER BY assets.id : Does this make any difference?

Comment: Okay so some further testing confirmed that a good chunk of the slowness is actually coming from the pgadmin interface that I was using to run this test. The query timer it includes will also take into account the full render time for every single returned row, and omitting that dropped the query time down to something way closer to what you were getting.